# OpenCL Kernel summatory

Tags: kernel, sum, opencl

I want to know if this is possible to do... I want to check inside of the kernel in java, if the array contains numbers and characters, and if yes, save how many times they appear in the output array.

```
private static String programSource =
            "__kernel void sampleKernel(__global const char *a, __global int *c){" +
            "   c[0]=0; c[1]=0;"+
            "   int gid = get_global_id(0);" +
            "   if((a[gid] > 64 && a[gid] < 91) || (a[gid] > 96 && a[gid] < 123)) c[0]+=1; "+
            "   else if(a[gid] > 47 && a[gid] < 58) c[1]+=1;" + 
            "}";
```

This is the code I have... but in the output array it always the number 1...
What is wrong? What would be the solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All work-items are modifying c[0] and c[1] at the same time, resulting in the wrong output.

One solution would be to use **atomic_inc**.  atomic_inc(c) instead of c[0]+=1, and atomic_inc(c+1) instead of c[1]+=1.

Next, since you have only two outputs, there will be a lot of collisions, and this will probably be quite slow.  A reduction-like algorithm will be preferable.

Comment: If I have understand it well it should be now so:? 
if((a[gid] > 64 && a[gid] < 91) || (a[gid] > 96 && a[gid] < 123)) atomic_inc(c); else if(a[gid] > 47 && a[gid] < 58) atomic_inc(c+1);
?
Thanks!